# When to use "quiet" and "silent"?

Tags: word-choice

Can anyone explain which context requires to use the adjective `quiet` and when I should use `silent` instead?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Can you expand your question with some examples of context that make the difference confusing to you? This has the makings of a good and potentially useful question.

Comment: Keep silent/keep quiet both mean "don't talk/open your mouth"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silence is the absence of sound.  It's an absolute adjective, so people don't usually say something is *very silent* or *silenter* unless they're playing with words.  If something makes no noise at all, it's *silent*.

*Quiet* means something is not very loud.  It's not an absolute adjective, so you can say something is *quieter* than something else.  If you're comparing several cars, you can say the one which makes the least noise is *the quietest*.

How do you decide which word to use?

- Use *silent* if there **is no sound**.
- Use *quiet* if there's sound, but it's **not very loud**.